# I want to create a graph for the Carseats dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I create a graph like this using the `Carseats` dataset in R?
the dataset is found here: https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/Carseats.csv

[image]

and also something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tell us where the `Carseats` data comes from (apparently it's in the `ISLR` package).  These plots are made with the `ggplot2` package: start [here](https://ggplot2-book.org/introduction.html)

Comment: It comes from here: https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/Carseats.csv

Answer (score 1):

start here then fiddle with it. You'll need the packages: {readr} {dplyr} and {ggplot2} to do this:

```r
carseats <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Carseats.csv")


carseats %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Price, y = Sales, color = US)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~ShelveLoc)
```

Comment: And to obtain something like this? https://imgur.com/a/tOyT8PK

Comment: Same answer. People are happy to help, but this is not a code-writing service. Now that @AndrewMcCartney has given you a starting point, you can try to adapt it to your other example.  When you run into trouble, feel free to post a **specific** example of something you're trying to do and why it's not working the way you want ...

Comment: Agree with what @BenBolker said--happy to help you get started but I'm not going to do your homework for you.